# protractor not able to open new tab window which contains pdf tab

Tags: selenium, jasmine, protractor

While testing one angular website there is button, When i am clicking on it - It should open new tab which contains pdf.

What i tried - Manual Execution working properly

1) I used **JAVA script Executor** but it's not working.

```
browser.executeScript("document.querySelector('My Query Selector').click();");
```

2) simple click also not opening new tab in chrome protractor testing

```
const elm = element(by.xpath("//button[@class='My Class Name']"));

elm.click();
```

> chrome Version = Version 74.0.3729.169 (Official Build) (64-bit)

```
browser.addMockModule('Infrastructure.SignalR', () => {
      angular.module('Infrastructure.SignalR', []);
    });
```

does this browser.addMockModule affects to not opening new tab ?

Comment: what is the behavior? is something happening on the browser?

Comment: nothing it just click and stay on screen...

Comment: I tried out with putting sleep but i am not getting any sucess

Comment: can you share the HTML?

Comment: i am absolutely sure that is not html issue it's blocking something

Answer (score 0):

Try using Control+Click to check whether it is working.

```
const elm = element(by.xpath("//button[@class='My Class Name']"));
Actions action=new Actions(driver);
action.keyDown(Keys.CONTROL).click(elm).keyUp(Keys.CONTROL).build().perform();
```

Comment: Already tried but not Working..I updated my question.. please go throug it.